# Converting a SQL statement to rails command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a situation where I need to fetch only few records from a particular active record query response.

```
@annotations = Annotations.select('*', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column_a) ORDER BY column_b)
```

Above is the query for which the `@annotations` is the Active Record Response on which I would like to apply the below logic. Is there a better way to write the below logic in rails way?

```
with some_table as
(
 select *, row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b) rn
 from the_table
)
select * from some_table
where (column_a = 'ABC' and rn <= 10) or (column_b <> 'AAA')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not provide CTEs in its high level API; however with a little Arel we can make this a sub query in the FROM clause

```
annotations_table = Annotation.arel_table 
sub_query = annotations_table.project(
  Arel.star,
  Arel.sql('row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b)').as(:rn)
)
query = Arel::Nodes::As.new(sub_query, Arel.sql(annotations_table.name))

Annotation.from(query).where(
  annotations_table[:column_a].eq('ABC').and(
    annotations_table[:rn].lt(10)
  ).or(annotations_table[:column_b].not_eq('AAA'))
)
```

The result will be a collection of `Annotation` objects using your CTE and the filters you described.

SQL:

```
select annotations.* 
from (
 select *, row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b) AS rn
 from annotations
) AS annotations
where (annotations.column_a = 'ABC' and annotations.rn <= 10) or (annotations.column_b <> 'AAA')
```

**Notes:**

- With a little extra work we could make this a CTE but it does not seem needed in this case
- We could use a bunch of hacks to transition this `row_number() over (partition by column_a order by column_b)` to Arel as well but it did not seem pertinent to the question.

Comment: Provided you have a fairly modern version of Rails and Ruby (2.7+) you can use endless and beginless ranges to create LT/GT/LTE/GTE conditions with the hash syntax. `where(column_a: 'ABC', rn: ..10).or(Anotation.where('annotations.column_b <> 'AAA')')`. In older versions you can use `10..Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: @max I always forget about that because it still feels awkward and almost dirty to me. Qualified Range means between, endless Range greater than equal to, beginingless range less than equal to, triple dot remove the equality, **too much magic**. I would almost prefer predication parsing e.g `where(column_a: 'ABC', rn: {lt_eq: 10})`

Comment: Yeah it is somewhat awkward and I can never remeber if `..` or `...` does LTE. I wish that `where` took a block and yielded the arel table or select manager or something so you could do `where { |a| a[:rn].gt(10) }`. Kind of like Squeel but with less metaprogramming insanity.

Comment: @max agreed especially since `sequel` offers this type of interface and `ransack` offers compound finders like `rn_lteq: 10`